# Ajax Load an entire page on History 'onpopsate'

Tags: jquery, browser-history, html5-history

I use this to create a new state:

```
//state 1
        history.pushState({ reload: true }, 'submodulo', '?submodulo=1');
//state2
        history.pushState({ reload: true }, 'submodulo', '?submodulo=2');
//state3
        history.pushState({ reload: true }, 'submodulo', '?submodulo=3');
```

I'd like to reload the content when user push the Back Button.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
          if (event.state !== null &amp;&amp; event.state.reload) {

              location.reload(true);

            }               
    };
```

But, this way, I will lost the states. It's like clicking in an entire new url. It does'nt keep the sequence. Is there another way to load an entire page, but in an ajax way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run an ajax call instead of reloading the page on popstate event.

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
   if (event.state !== null && event.state.reload) {
              $.ajax({
                url: 'load-content.php',
                success: function( response ) {
                     $('#main-content').replaceWith( response );      
                  }
              });
   }               
};
```

In the targeted PHP file load your content depending on the url or given parameters and on success replace your content with the generated one.

Comment: States still get wrong. Can't, for instance, push back 2 times. The first one works fine, but not the second. Or push back and then forward.

Comment: Do you get any errors or hints in your response? Offtopic: That's a thing a noticed on a few websites using ajax to navigate.